# Displaying an image directly from the webserver in the center of the screen

Tags: html, image, webserver, alignment, center

I am loading an image from the webserver and it loads aligned to the left. It fits to screen automatically and it also has a magnifying glass icon that allows me to zoom in to the image without any scaling. This is great, but am I able to have it load in the center?

Comment: Why do you need this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most recent browsers center the image already, like the latest FireFox.

However you can't force that behaviour if the program don't do that already by itself.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. It displays the image perfectly! No need of custom javascript or css to do what should be default behavior :) :) :)

Comment: I updated to the latest Chrome and it does not have the same behavior. Lame :(

Comment: I know you can't control that. But you can use a different methods like Lightbox or Colorbox scripts. They will overlay the centered image on your webpage.